# Don't Echo Out cURL

Tags: php, curl

When I use this code:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
$statuses = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I am returned what I want, but if I just use that - `$statuses` is echoed out onto the page.

How can I stop this?

Comment: is there something wrong with if we add directly echo $statuses  ?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Put this on line 2:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Answer (score 73):

Include this option before `curl_exec()`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: I like this answer more because it is far clearer that you are specifying a boolean value, not a number.

Comment: Additionally it specifies that it must be put before the exec.  Though that is relatively intuitive, it may save some people a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, make sure you didn't set CURLOPT_VERBOSE to true, if you add this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
```

there will be output from cUrl, even with CURL_RETURNTRANSFER set to true