# Post updates of activity on website to Facebook wall of a user or page or wall of Website based on php 

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi friends i am devloping a website on which activity like answering to a question by a user a  post created by him i need to show on his wall or my website wall or page but i am not getting how to do it .

i googled a lot .

and refrenced this links

[Post on someones wall using Facebook API PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133170/post-on-someones-wall-using-facebook-api-php)

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/09/working-with-facebook-sdk-permissions.html

[Posting status via Facebook's graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850774/posting-status-via-facebooks-graph-api)

i downloaded facebook sdk and created an app  to but its not working since i dont have my site  its not started .

i tried most of the examples but i was limited since i dont have app and my knowledge of fb is limited .

i would like to know is it possible for me to

1. create post on user wall even if he has not given me permision wihtout any app .
2. In case if the user register via fb and grants me acess to post on wall. how to post   on his wall if you consider i have an test app  then .
3. if i want to update my company website with top ten post for each day. how can i post that on my wall or an fb page . ( would i need an app ?)

any help will be greatly appreciated .

since i am not sure about what i need php sdk , graph api , facebook-connect or so so.

there documentation is so confusing and they keep changing there api so old links not working  ..

can any one guide me on it . or link me a breif detailed explaination on how to achieve it step by step ,

So i can Accomplish this task.

Comment: atleast if you downvote then tell why :) . i have done proper research  and cam continuing it . i just wanted to know if someone has dome it to guide me how .

Comment: I guess the reason for the down votes is that you are not asking for the answer to a specific problem. You do not provide any code snippets so it seems you have not tried to solve your problems by your self in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

1) You cannot post on someones wall without their permission. You can prompt them using the FB.ui method though without them having to grant permission https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

2) When you do have a site and an application then the user will have to grant the appropriate permissions, you can then use the information here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/ If you scroll down there is a section titled "Post a link to a User's wall using the Graph API"

3) How do you measure "Top 10"? If these are on your website anyway, then you should know what php code you need to display them. To post them to your page on FB you would need to use a page access token and authenticate as your page (you would need to grant the "manage_pages" permission to your account) and then you could post a your page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/  The alternative is to create a custom tab for the page that calls in to your own website backend and displays the top 10 posts from that. Info about page tabs can be found here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ . Now provided you have php knowledge you should be able to figure it out from these links. If you don't then I'm afraid you need to ask more specific questions and read some books or tutorials, otherwise this question would be too open ended

Comment: +1 For actually answering this question

Comment: ya its a very general question thanks for answering . +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

You can post on a friend wall without any permissions if you use the [JavaSriptSDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/), but in this case you cannot control the message he posts, unly to attach a link to an url and configure the image and the title.

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    to:'the Facebook ID of the person you wanna send',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'http://emplido.com',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

You will need to have a facebook application for this. Make sure that the `link` is pointing to the domain of your facebook application, defined on `developers.facebook.com`.